Better way to convert strings in json object to ints in c# class
Given the following JSON object
[
  {
    "change_date": "20211118 2134",
    "inspection_id": "74207177",
    "insp_unit_id": "185883333",
  }
]

And the following C# class.
public class Root
{
    public string change_date { get; set; }
    public string inspection_id { get; set; }
    public string insp_unit_id { get; set; }
}

What is a good way to return int's instead of strings.  I'm currently adding methods to the class like below.
public int inspection_id_int()
{
    return Convert.toint32(inspection_id );
}

Looking for advice on a better way to achieve this.  I'm using System.Text.JSON and deserializing via JsonSerializer.Deserialize.

Let's ignore the date field for now - then if the IDs are given to you as a string - what makes you think you can handle them as numerical? What stops the creator of that data to send an id like "7420717B" ? And even IF they are numerical as per contract, what makes you think they are within [int.Min .. int.Max] ?

They are all ints.  I suppose they could change at some later date, but it's been this way for the last 20 years.  The datetime ones I'm converting using parse exact.

Do you perform any calculation on the ids or why do want them as int? I don't see the need, right now. Just more problems than simply taking them for what they are: arbitrary strings.

You could of course have a custom converter for your Root class ... do you want to keep the original string and have both string and int?

No need to keep the original string.

In that case, I'd try the custom converter. That will probably also solve your Date field conversion.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-8.0, you can set JsonSerializerOptions to allow reading number from strings (so just contert the properties to int.

^^ You may still need a custom converter for that date.

Would leading zeroes ever be used? If so, it needs to be a string.

You may (/probably) want a read-onlyproperty rather than a function for the interesting value

It depends on what you want to have as int, change_date is not valid number (has space in the middle).
But when it comes to other fields, just decalre them as int
class Root
{
    public string change_date { get; set; }
    public int inspection_id { get; set; }
    public int insp_unit_id { get; set; }
}

and then pass JsonSerializerOptions with NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString to Deserialize method:
var json = @"[
  {
    ""change_date"": ""20211118 2134"",
    ""inspection_id"": ""74207177"",
    ""insp_unit_id"": ""185883333""
  }
]";

var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root[]>(
    json,
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
    });


Generally, data from an API should follow the API's schema, so you would use a string property for the data object since that's how it is serialized.
You could then use another class to represent the actual object you want to use in your app, and map from the int to the string when creating your objects from the API data. AutoMapper is a good library to make most of these mappings trivial, and lets you use custom mappings that could be much more complex than just converting a string to an integer (or a date, as you probably need for the change_date field.
The process would be something like:

Get the data from the API as-is
Map the data to your app objects
Use the objects however you want in your app


It's better to check if you can convert the value directly to int else, you will run into exception.
public int inspection_id_int()
{
    if (int.TryParse(inspection_id, out int result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}


In this case, an exception would actually be preferable because you are dealing with a programming error if this conversion fails.

@Fildor, the return -1 can be updated to throw an exception instead

You could do the following:
Create your own converter
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => int.Parse(reader.GetString());

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}

decorate your class and change property to int
public class Root
{
    public string change_date { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
    public int inspection_id { get; set; }

    public string insp_unit_id { get; set; }
}

Then it will work as you expected
